# Save to more than one entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

For a detail view I would like to let the user leave notes for each item.  The app is for a data-driven website.  In the web version, the web app stores notes in a separate table with a field for the itemid.

In Core Data I have an entity of items and another entity of notes.  The notes entity has an attribute called `itemid`.  When user creates a note the first time, it stores the `itemid` in the note record.

My question is when you pull up the item for editing how can you simultaneously pull up the right note based on the note having a certain `itemid`?

In a database situation you could do a join, or from a web page you could make two separate requests to the two tables but I am somewhat flummoxed by how to do this with Core Data.

Do you have to put a relationship to the note and therefore have the `noteid` in the item row?

If so would you be able to access the note attribute using the item object?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

This is what I am using to save information.  I just don't know how to make sure I'm saving it for right note.

```
self.managedObjectContext = [IDModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
NSString *noteText = _notesView.text;
NSNumber *itemId = self.item.itemid;
// Populate Record
[self.note setValue:noteText forKey:@"note"];
[self.note setValue:itemId forKey:@"itemid"];

Model (simplified):

Item:
name NSString
itemid: Integer 64

Note:
note NSString
noteid: Integer 64
itemid: Integer 64

  Edit:
```

Code to try to link note and item while creating both...

```
//in save method
        // Create Entity
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        // Initialize New Record ie newNote
        NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        // Populate Record
        [record setValue:note forKey:@"note"];
        [record setValue:localid forKey:@"localnid"];

        // Save Record
        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
//   If note saved, save new item…
             if (itemlength>1) {
            Items *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“Item” inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            newItem.item = item;
              newItem.note = self.note
//This is null as note does not seem to pick up newly created note.
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
             }
             }
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between these two entities? That's usually how you'd do this in Core Data.

Comment: Not yet.  What should the relationship be?

Comment: Are you aware of fetch requests?

Comment: A fetch request is used to fetch the item from the items entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use a relationship between the `Item` and `Note` entities.  To create a relationship just Ctrl-drag from one entity to the other in the data model editor.  Note that Xcode automatically adds an inverse relationship:

[image: Screenshot of ERD]

I've renamed the relationships for clarity - you can tailor the details of the relationship (name, one-one v one-many, delete rule, etc) in the panel on the right.  In the example above, the `Item` entity has three properties: 2 attributes and 1 relationship.  Given an `Item` object, say `myItem`, the values for these properties can be accessed using the Key Value Coding methods: `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:`.  For example, if `attribute` is defined as a string:

```
 NSString *myStringValue = [myItem valueForKey:@"attribute"];
 [myItem setValue:@"new value for attribute" forKey:@"attribute"];
```

That's very long-winded.  So to make life easier, use the "Create NSManagedObject subclass..." option.  Xcode will configure each entity to be a subclass of NSManagedObject and will create new class files (.h/.m or .swift) with details of the properties.  For the example `Item`:

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *attribute;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *attribute1;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) Note *note;
```

The thing to realise is that the `note` relationship is of **class** Note.  It's not a foreign key, or a noteid, that you have to use to lookup the corresponding `Note` object.  It **is** the Note object.  Under the hood, CoreData is adding primary keys and foreign keys to the underlying tables, but all that aggravation is abstracted away.

Having created the subclasses, you can use the dot-accessors for the object properties:

```
NSString *myStringValue = myItem.attribute;
myItem.attribute = @"new value for attribute";
```

For the relationship, if you have an `Item` object called `myItem` and a `Note` object called `myNote`, you can set the relationship value with:

```
myItem.note = myNote;
```

or equivalently:

```
myNote.item = myItem;
```

(Note: use one or the other, not both; CoreData automatically sets inverse relationships for you).

Now, you have the added complication of a web server from which the Item objects and Note objects are downloaded.  And on your web server, your `Notes` table has a field for the `itemid`, which is used to link Items and Notes.  At some point, you want to link up Note objects and Item objects using the itemid.  The usual approach would be to do it once (as soon as the CoreData objects are synchronised from the server), set the relationship accordingly, and thenceforth use the relationship rather than the itemid to get the note for a given item.  For example, if you are creating a new `Note` object, and the itemid from the server is "1234", you might do this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemid == %@", @"1234"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
// should check for nil results/error
if (results.count > 0) {
    // found (at least) one Item with itemid == @"1234"
    // use the first to set the relationship
    newNote.item = results[0];
}
```

Then whenever you have a particular Item object, you can access the corresponding note using

```
Note *myNote = myItem.note;
```

Furthermore, you can cascade the dot-notation, so get the value of `attribute` for the Note for myItem, use:

```
NSString *noteText = myItem.note.attribute;
```

**EDIT**

Your save method is very close: either set `self.note = record` before  you save, or use `newItem.note = record`:

```
    //in save method
    // Create Entity
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    // Initialize New Record ie newNote
    NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    // Populate Record
    [record setValue:note forKey:@"note"];
    [record setValue:localid forKey:@"localnid"];

    // Save Record
    NSError *error = nil;

    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    //   If note saved, save new item…
        if (itemlength>1) {
            Items *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“Item” inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            newItem.item = item;
            newItem.note = record;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK.  Thx for thorough answer!  This item view controller does not do its own fetch.  It gets item object from prepareforsegue from a tableviewcontroller that uses NSFetchedResultsController.  Should I put the predicate in the tableviewcontroller FRC?

Comment: @user1904273 How/when do you load data into CoreData from your web server?  It is then that you should fix up the relationship.

Comment: Right now I am just getting it to work with locally created content.  I have an id scheme for local content until it is synched. noteid is 1,2,3,4 etc. When a note is created, the itemid , say 1, is stored in the note entity as itemid.  The question is how to display the note and item (or save them together upon editing) based on the itemid in the note object--in other words how to tell the two entities which attribute to link up on.

Comment: If you are entirely local, there is no need to use a noteid or itemid to link the Item to the Note.  Just use `myNote.item = myItem` as set out in my answer.  So, for example, if you have a table view showing Items and `prepareForSegue` passes the chosen `Item` to a detail VC, you could access its existing note as `Note *existingNote = self.item.note` or create a new Note (with `Note *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEnityForName:@"Note"];`) then link it up with `newNote.item = self.item`.

Comment: getting no known class method for insertNewObjectForEntityForName

Comment: Sorry: `Note *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEnityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:context];`

Comment: Ok, creating the newNote ok.  But when I set newNote.item = self.item and log them to console, they both show null.  Could this be because I am creating item with following:  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
        [record setValue:item forKey:@"item"]; and thens save...

Comment: @user1904273 That looks basically OK, though "Item**s**" should be "Item".  How do you pass `record` to the code where you set the relationship to newNote?  Can you edit your post to include the full code?

Comment: I added code.  Problem seems to be that after saving record, I am losing it i.e. losing new note object.  I tried moving newItem.note=self.note before save and changing it to =self.record and saving note and item at same time but note still null.

Comment: @user1904273 I think your code is very close.  I've amended my answer to (I hope) fix it.

Comment: Ok.  This worked though it does give yellow warning 'Incompatible pointer types assigning to Notes* from NSManagedObject but thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To reach your goal you need to create a `NSFetchRequest` passing it the right `NSPredicate`.

The fetch request will be run against your `Note` entity. The predicate will allow you to specify that the `Note` object you want to retrieve is the one for that specific `noteid`.

So, if you have a 1-to-1 relationship between `Item` and `Note`, the `NSPredicate` should like the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipToItem.propertyForItemId == %@", yourItemId];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Here I suppose you've a created a relationship between the two entities, otherwise you need to do it manually. Can you provide how your model looks like?

Comment: Have added the model to question.  I have created a one to one, two-way relationship from item to note.  However, I have not successfully connected itemid in the two entities as I cannot find way to do so in relationship inspector.  Where would I do fetch?  The screen is currently loaded from a tableview of items using prepareforsegue.